# Check if user specifies a flag?

Tags: gulp

Is it possible to check if a user has specified a flag eg.

```
gulp --test=yes
```

I'd get the flag via:

```
yargs.argv.test;
```

And if they have not halt the gulp script and output an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a global flag that is required for every task you can just check it first thing in your gulpfile and [`exit()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_exit_code) if it hasn't been provided:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var yargs = require('yargs');

if (!yargs.argv.test) {
  console.error('You need to provide the --test flag!');
  process.exit(1);
}

gulp.task('someTask', function() {
  console.log('Value of --test flag is :' + yargs.argv.test);
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  console.log('Value of --test flag is :' + yargs.argv.test);
});
```

If the flag is only valid for a certain task just check it in that particular task:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var yargs = require('yargs');

gulp.task('someTask', function() {
  if (!yargs.argv.test) {
    console.error('You need to provide the --test flag for someTask!');
    process.exit(1);
  }
  console.log('Value of --test flag is :' + yargs.argv.test);
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
  console.log('This task does not need the --test flag!');
});
```

Comment: Thanks, will process.exit(1); stop any further processing? Also what does the '1' mean?

Comment: Yes, the gulp process will immediately terminate and no further processing will take place. When you terminate a process you can send a signal (exit code) to the parent process. Sending `0` signifies successful termination (nothing went wrong). Sending `1` (or any other signal that isn't `0`) signifies that something went wrong (e.g. bad user input).